# Converting a table to an ORM schema

Tags: orm, modeling, schema

I'm trying to convert this table into an ORM schema: [image: table]

The solution given by the book is this one: [image: solution]
It connects all the paramether to the Member one. This is my solution, which I think it's less complicated, but I don't know if it is equivalent: [image: my solution]

What do you think about my solution? Is it right?

Comment: "Is it right" isn't a meaningful question.  The only possible answer is "yes, if it best meets your specific software's requirements."

Comment: To expand on what @RobertHarvey is saying, take a look at [Lehman's SPE-classfication](https://www.expressionsofchange.org/lehman-spe-classification/). The two main points are 1) the most constrained type of problem (S types) can have multiple solutions, eg: sorting - quick sort, bubble sort... And 2) that you are presuming that you have all the requirements and that they will never ever change. It may pay to have a simpler solution, or it may pay to have a very constrained solution, it depends on how you expect requirements to change overtime.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Object Role Modeling (ORM) is a specific approach to developing for database. It does not involve software requirements. "Is it right" clearly has meaning for ORM, particularly in terms of a university textbook.

Comment: This seems to be an exercise in modeling a specific real world scenario. It looks to me more of a test of domain knowledge than modeling. Is sport an entity? I don't think so, but the point I am trying to make is that stack exchange can't answer the question if you modeled the scenario correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, I'd say that it is wrong, since a person's heart rate does not have a reaction time. Similarly, a sport such as tennis does not make a booking, a member makes a booking.